# Select failing validation on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem in my validations. Everytime I try to save an object using text from the selection field the validation fails.

Everytime I try to save or change a new model I get an error saying that my category column is not inclued in the valid values.

This is the validation I have in my model:

```rb
CATEGORIES = %w'public private filantropic'
validates :category, inclusion: { in: CATEGORIES }
```

And this is the field I have in my view:

```rb
th = f.label :category
td = f.select :category,
options_for_select(HealthUnit::CATEGORIES)
```

Comment: How your `select tag options` looks like?

Comment: They are supposed to be the array of words CATEGORIES

Comment: Does `category` value pass to controller? Maybe, it's blank?